# How to have two gradients side by side in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, gradient

I want to have two linear gradients side by side without putting them inside a different Container() each

My code:

```
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              // Instead of two different colors here I want to have the two other Linear gradients
              // with each having two other different colors that go from top to bottom
              Color(0xff5a0dbe),
              Color(0xff004773),
            ],
            stops: [0.5, 0.5],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
          ),
        ),
        child: const Center(
            child: Text(
          "sds",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        )),
      ),
```

What I got is

[image]

What I want is

[image]

Comment: why not use a second container ?

Comment: because If I do that then I will have to use Stack to position the other elements on top on their places and I don't want to do that, that's why Im looking for another alternative

Comment: it can archive by two gradient  containers, let me provide a demo snippet for it

Comment: ok you like to avoid using `stack`?  you can also use `CustomPainter` or `Clipper`, that might be more complicated than this. or `CustomMultiChildLayout`

Comment: You can also use just single `Column` and background for this UI, no dont need to position them

Comment: I was thinking of doing the last one as a last resort, but as for the CostumPainter or Clipper I don't have exp with them so how would that work for me Idk.

Comment: I think you can follow my answer, the simpler way to archive this UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a `Column` to place the widgets as you described on comment, no need to worry about positioning widget. Using `Stack` with two `Container`

```dart
 return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        //for future purpose if needed
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter, // defult topLeft
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Color(0xff5a0dbe),
                            Color(0xff004773),
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          // stops: [0.5, 0.5],
                          // tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Color(0xff00436D),
                            Color(0xff031420),
                          ],
                          // stops: [0.5, 0.5],
                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          // tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                // dont need it, 
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                child: Column(
                  // do everything on column
                  children: [
                   
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: you can find more about layout [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)